# How Inject prototype spring bean to singleton bean

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I want to change my pojo class to spring, I have a problem for injection protoype bean to singelton bean, My old code was as follows:

```
public class InsertBankBusiness(){

    private ServiceInput input;
    
    public void doBusiness(ServiceInput input){
        this.input = input;
        ....
        }
},

public class BankService(){
    
    public void definebank(ServiceInput input){
        InsertBankBusiness insertBankBusiness = InsertBankBusiness ()
        insertBankBusiness .doBusiness(input)
        }

}
```

Insert BankBusiness class is not thread safe and I need to instantiate from it for every service call, I have now rewritten the code as follows:

```
@Component(value="insertBankBusiness")
@Scope(value="request", proxyMode=TARGET_CLASS)
public class InsertBankBusiness(){

    private ServiceInput input;

    public void doBusiness(ServiceInput input){
        this.input = input;
        ....
        }
},

@Service(value="bankService")
public class BankService(){

    @Autowire InsertBankBusiness insertBankBusiness;
    
    public void definebank(ServiceInput input){
        insertBankBusiness.doBusiness(input)
        }

}
```

Is the behavior of the second scenario the same as the first scenario?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not the same.

In the first scenario, you create `InsertBankBusiness` service each time when access it, but in the second scenario, service creates once per HTTP request.

You need to use [`Prototype`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/3.0.0.M3/reference/html/ch04s04.html#beans-factory-scopes-prototype) scope instead of [`Request`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/3.0.0.M3/reference/html/ch04s04.html#beans-factory-scopes-request) to have the same behavior.

```java
    @Scope(value= "prototype", proxyMode=TARGET_CLASS)
    public class InsertBankBusiness {

    }
```

`InsertBankBusiness` injected correctly via Scoped Proxy. Each time the method on the proxy object is called, the proxy decides itself whether to create a new instance of the real object or reuse the existing one.